# #link easing, how is this called? and is there a plugin to animate this with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure how this links are called something.com/#link I would like to animate this browser action. But since I don't know how they are called cannot find correct jquery plugin or wiki.

Ty,

Comment: it's a hash. you reference it with `location.hash`.

Comment: something like this? http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

Comment: @IsaacFife these are cool, but are page transitions I'm looking for hash tag transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The #link is a hash (or anchor), that usually is a id of the page. The browser do scroll to anchor automatically, but if you want customise this scroll, is like this:

```
if(location.hash) {
  _hash = location.hash; // Stores hash
  location.hash = ''; // Removes the native scroll of browser
  var anchor = "#el_"+_hash;
  var el = $(anchor); // Gets target element
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: el.offset().top}, 'slow', function(){
    location.hash = _hash; // Inserts the hash in url again
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I what about this way of doing it? can you explain diff? $('#selectcitydd').localScroll({duration:800, hash:true});

Comment: `jQuery.localScroll()` is a jQuery Plugin that does other things besides. This is a basic example just to animate the scroll of the page to a point.